# How to add a value of a variable to name of another one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JS code:

```
let itemsCount = 1;

addButton.onclick = () => {

    itemsCount++;

    let newElement + ${itemCount} = document.createElement("li");

    newElement ${itemCount}.textContent = `thing_to_do ${itemCount}`;

    parent.appendChild(newElement + ${itemsCount});

    
}
```

And have an 'onclick' event which increases the value of `itemsCount` for 1 with each click and creates an `li` element, and then appends to it the text, and I want each element to have its personal name which is: `newElement` and then I want to add to this text a value of variable `itemsCount`. But when I run the code, it gives me a syntax error and that is because of the ```${itemCount}.

Is there any way to add the `itemCount`'s value to the variable name, if it is possibe?

Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Always check the error console.

Comment: Don’t use “numbered” variable names, use an _array_.

Comment: Since the variable doesn't exist outside the scope of `AddButton.onClick` there's no reason to use the itemCount here at all, you could just call it `newElement` and the behaviour would be the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```js
let itemsCount = 0;

const addButton = document.getElementById("button");

addButton.onclick = () => {

    itemsCount++;

    let newElement = document.createElement("li");

    newElement.textContent = `thing_to_do ${itemsCount}`;
    
  document.getElementById("container").append(newElement)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">add</button>
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

I corrected your syntax errors, and added some HTML for reference.

```
let newElement + ${itemCount}
```

You cannot create variables like  that's simply incorrect syntax. You are using string templating without backticks, and in a variable, you can't do that.

```
newElement ${itemCount}.textContent
```

Again you are using string templating in a variable name, and expecting that to work.

Remember to check and understand your console errors, they will tell you when you do wrong syntax.